# Possible to do multifield range query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I would like to execute a range query against multiple fields, or a field with a suffix, like `markups.*`. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in `Nest` or `Elasticsearch`. For example this query in ES returns results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
        "markups.1": {
          "gte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000",
          "lte": "2015-05-20T10:49:07.608"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

But this suffixed query returns nothing:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
        "markups.*": {
          "gte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000",
          "lte": "2015-05-20T10:49:07.608"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT 1, Here is the default mapping for the field:

```
"markups": {
"properties": {
"1": {
"type": "date",
"format": "dateOptionalTime"
}
}
}
```

EDIT 2, complete exception:

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[UNsBpzvUT0eRh455sPvFoA][nyc01check-20150520-170219][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Caregiver][inet[/192.168.2.223:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[nyc01check-20150520-170219][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\ \ \"query\": {\ \ \"query_string\": {\ \ \"fields\": [\"markups.*\"], \ \ \"query\": \"[2015-01-01 TO 2015-05-20]\"\ \ }\ \ }\ \ }]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"2015-01-01\"]; }{[bZjjVX5zTGKDkfTsSU0lIg][nyc01check-20150520-170219][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][inet[/192.168.2.227:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[nyc01check-20150520-170219][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\ \ \"query\": {\ \ \"query_string\": {\ \ \"fields\": [\"markups.*\"], \ \ \"query\": \"[2015-01-01 TO 2015-05-20]\"\ \ }\ \ }\ \ }]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"2015-01-01\"]; }{[pzbyI5Y_TvyzL-tpZGN1HQ][nyc01check-20150520-170219][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Monolith][inet[/192.168.2.224:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[nyc01check-20150520-170219][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\ \ \"query\": {\ \ \"query_string\": {\ \ \"fields\": [\"markups.*\"], \ \ \"query\": \"[2015-01-01 TO 2015-05-20]\"\ \ }\ \ }\ \ }]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"2015-01-01\"]; }{[bZjjVX5zTGKDkfTsSU0lIg][nyc01check-20150520-170219][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][inet[/192.168.2.227:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[nyc01check-20150520-170219][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\ \ \"query\": {\ \ \"query_string\": {\ \ \"fields\": [\"markups.*\"], \ \ \"query\": \"[2015-01-01 TO 2015-05-20]\"\ \ }\ \ }\ \ }]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"2015-01-01\"]; }{[aoWs6XiITJGkBXCLog6eNA][nyc01check-20150520-170219][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Nomad][inet[/192.168.2.226:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[nyc01check-20150520-170219][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\ \ \"query\": {\ \ \"query_string\": {\ \ \"fields\": [\"markups.*\"], \ \ \"query\": \"[2015-01-01 TO 2015-05-20]\"\ \ }\ \ }\ \ }]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"2015-01-01\"]; }]",
"status": 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use `query_string`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["markups.*"], 
      "query": "[2015-01-01T00:00:00.000 TO 2015-05-20T10:49:07.608]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this results in a "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query]" and 400 status code

Comment: Yeah I noticed that before and corrected it in my testing. It still doesn't work. I changed it to a specific field like "markups.1" and it works as anticipated.

Comment: Ok. What is the mapping of that field, can you post it?

Comment: it's just using the default

Comment: ... ok then. For me it works, just so you know. The unknown now is the mapping.

Comment: Yep I've added the mapping

Comment: You haven't posted the complete exception. And it happens because you have a `long` field in there. The `markups.*` matches the `markupBy` field, as well. Of course it will not work with a date range.

Comment: You should have kept the initial mapping in the post, it is important. Why have you edited it?

Comment: So, the mapping that is in the post now is the correct one?

Comment: Strange, then. Works for me. What is the complete exception that you get?

Comment: I suggest looking at the mapping of the index you are actually searching, because it might match more fields than you think. And the exception shows that it's matching a number typed field. The `long` field you had in the first mapping is a very good example of such a field.

Comment: If `markups` is the type name and not an inner object in your mapping, it doesn't have to appear in the range or query string query. Simply use `*` and it will work.

Comment: @AndreiStefan is correct, issue was with my mappings